# Bounce-back error "550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable" occasionally to random existing domain mailboxes

Tags: email, exchange-server-2010, email-bounces

Occasionally when mailing random people on our exchange server, the sender receives a bounce back that says: 
The e-mail account does not exist at the organization this message was sent to.  Check the e-mail address, or contact the recipient directly to find out the correct address.
            <  #5.1.1 SMTP; 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable>

Now the email is sent to the correct email address and usually after several minutes if the sender attempts to send the email again, it goes through just fine.
At the time that this occurs, there are no errors in the event viewer and no logs in the exchange server. 
From all that I read on this error, everyone reports that it means the mailbox doesn't exist. 
Has anybody every encountered an issue like this?

Comment: I've got a php application running and it sends off emails regularly, sometimes it goes through and other times it doesn't - no idea where to start with this issue!